# couldn't find a debug adapter descriptor for debug type 'solidity'(Extension might have failed to activate)

Tags: visual-studio-code, blockchain, solidity, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to run a simple code in VScode.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract WavePortal {
    constructor() {
        console.log("Yo yo, I am a contract and I am smart");
    }
}
```

And as i try to compile the code, it shows the following error

[Click to open the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMl2V.png)

This is my launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "solidityMeadow",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug Solidity (via unit test run)"
        },
        {
            "type": "solidity",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug Solidity (via contract entry point)"
        },
        {
            "type": "solidity",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug Solidity"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try reinstalling your extension. This is a known error. Happened after last VSCode upgrade.

Comment: I tried reinstalling the solidity debugger extension but still, it shows the same error.

Comment: have you found a solution yet? I have the same problem. @KrishJani

Answer (score 2):

First, it prompt me to install "Solidity Debugger" in VS Code.
Then, it prompt me to install .NET Core 2.1 SDK and I have installed .NET 7.0 SDK.

"Blockchain Development Kit for Ethereum" is deprecated so I have installed the "truffle for VS Code".

If I hit F5 once, it will says compile successfully.

If I hit F5 twice, "couldn't find a debug adapter descriptor for debug type 'solidity'(Extension might have failed to activate)" error will still appear.

However, I can still compile and publish it into blockchain.

Answer (score 0):

Im on M1 PRO and this is what I done and than "couldn't find a debug adapter descriptor..." error alert was gone and I was able to select host application and start debugging:

- I downloaded Visual Studio Code by clicking on "download" button on they web, than VSCode-darwin-universal.zip was downloaded and I installed app to my Application folder. (Just reinstall)
- I uninstall ExtendScript plugin and install it again
- I killed (right click and "close" on app icon in dock) VS app and than I started it with ROSETA (info option in context menu and there is checkbox)

My launch.json:

```
    {
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
    
        {
            "type": "extendscript-debug",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "extendScript-Debug attach"
        }
    ]
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

no idea if help is still needed. But in case someone finds this post. I had the same problem. But then I fixed it for me. What I did was to install the extension "Blockchain Development Kit for Ethereum" in VSCode. Then just create a new project using CTRL+SHIFT+P and type in "Blockchain:". Choose the option "Create a Solidity Project". Should fix this error.